# How to find the slope of a graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.loglog(length,time,'--')
```

where length and time are lists.

How do I find the linear fit slope of this graph?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you have matplotlib then you must also have numpy installed since it is a dependency. Therefore, you could use [numpy.polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html#numpy.polyfit) to find the slope:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

length = np.random.random(10)
length.sort()
time = np.random.random(10)
time.sort()
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(np.log(length), np.log(time), 1)
print(slope)
plt.loglog(length, time, '--')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This would be true if the graph is a line. In case it is a curve and the slope changes at different points a diffrential is needed. Try the diff function.

Comment: Can you please provide some more details about the function.

Comment: @Peter: `polyfit` (in its simplest incarnation) takes 3 args: the `x`-data, `y`-data, and the degree of polynomial. Since you are looking for a linear fit, the 3rd arg is set to 1. `polyfit` then returns the coefficients of the best-fit polynomial, which in this case means the slope and y-intercept. HTH.

Comment: Note that `np.log()` is the natural logarithm, while `plt.loglog()` rescales the data to base-10 logarithm. 
Use `np.log10()` instead, then the fitted line can be plotted using the relation  `y = x**slope * 10**(intercept)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take advantage of np.array to change your list to an array, then do the other calculations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Fitting_Log = np.polyfit(np.array(np.log(length)), np.array(np.log(time)), 1)   
Slope_Log_Fitted = Fitting_Log[0]

Plot_Log = plt.plot(length, time, '--')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```